# Advice on DB structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to make a database, but everytime I look at what I need and how to do it I think a different solution is better. I will describe my situation below and would like to know what would be the best way to go about and why:

I currently have an excel file with my requirements, it contains a list of categories, sub categories and respective questions that need filling in and the people they need to relate to. This would normally be a simple case of storing the category, subcategory in a table, linking it to a question table and then having an answer table that refers to the question and person table.
as such:

```
Person:
personID: int identifier
personName: nvarchar(50)

Info:
infoID: int identifier
infoCat: nvarchar(50)
infoSubCat: nvarchar(50)

Question
questionID: int identifier
questionText: nvarchar(100)
questionInfo: FK relating to infoID

Answer:
answerID: int identifier
answerQuestion: FK relating to questionID
answerPerson: FK relating to PersonID
answerNumber: int
```

The problem I'm facing here though, is that the answer is not always going to be a number. There are some questions that require me to store a `bit` or a `text` value.

The other solution I could think of is denormalising the question, having a table with `Info` and `Question` merged, and then a `Answers` table:

```
Answers:
AnswersID: int identifier
AnswersPerson: FK relating to PersonId
Answer1: int
Answer2: bit
Answer3: int
etc..
```

And finally I can also make the answer column have `nvarchar` instead of `int`, and just store `numerical` and `boolean` values in it as required. (This seems like the simplest solution, but I need to regulary back up the answers to a different DB where I have no control over, so I must ensure the values are transferable)

I am looking to find out what would be the best method for me, if it is one of the ones I have mentioned or one that I could not think of myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Second (denormalized) solution is very bad, don't do it. Look up `sql_variant`, it may simplify your first solution.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks, I was unaware of the existance of `sql_variant`. After looking into it, I am going to have a go making my first solution but replacing the `int` on the answer with `sql_variant`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve my problem, I used dasblinkenlight's suggestion of using `sql_variant` as type for my `answer` column. This result s in my answer table looking  like:

```
Answer:
answerID: int identifier
answerQuestion: FK relating to questionID
answerPerson: FK relating to PersonID
answerNumber: sql_variant
```

And it is working very well for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize and desalinize any value to string and from string. And you can store value type to second field.

For example:
answerValueType: int
answerValue: nvarchar(255)